# Can we calculate the percentage of red blood cells which are destroyed per day if we assume that all red blood cells have a lifespan of 120 days?

Tags: arithmetic

Approximately 1% of red blood cells are destroyed per day. I was wondering if we could derive this from the assumption that all red blood cells have a lifespan of 120 days.

I think we should assume that the concentration of red blood cells is constant and that red blood cells are continuously created and destroyed at a constant and equal rate.

Comment: Well, assuming a uniform distribution of age among red blood cells on any day, you would expect $\frac{1}{120}$ of the red blood cells to be destroyed. This is close enough to $1\%$ to maybe think the $1\%$ you have is an approximation to this figure.

Answer (score 2):

The formula for the [Mean Time to Faliure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures) says that $t=\frac1p$, where $t$ is the lifetime of an object and $p$ is the fraction of objects that fail.